# How do I get the value of specific cells on a gridview based on checkbox selections on the same row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I get data from an API and put it into a dataTable:

```
DataTable showsTable = Transporter.GetDataTableFromAPI(callingURL);

gvShows.DataSource = showsTable;
gvShows.DataBind();
```

I then add a new column to this table in the dataBind event:

```
protected void gvShows_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvShows.Rows)
            {
                var tcCheckCell = new TableCell();
                var chkCheckBox = new CheckBox();
                tcCheckCell.Controls.Add(chkCheckBox);
                row.Cells.AddAt(0, tcCheckCell);
            }
        }
```

On a button click, I want to get 3 cell values based on what row is CHECKED.

The values are:

- dataSource
- showId
- episodeId

I basically want to do...

For each checked row, get me the values of the columns dataSource, showId, and episodeId and put it into 3 different variables.

I'm not sure if this is right or how to finish it:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvShows.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox chk = row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkCheckBox") as CheckBox;
                if (chk != null && chk.Checked)
                {
                    dataSource = ...
                    showId = ...
                    episodeId = ...
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvShows.Rows)
{
    CheckBox chk = row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkCheckBox") as CheckBox;
    if (chk != null && chk.Checked)
    {
        //Access the data written in cell
        dataSource = row.Cells[1].Text; 
        //if you are using DataKeys in GridView, which I particularly like to do
        //(and it's useful for data you do not dsiplay), you 
        //can access data like this:
        showId = gvShows.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["showId"].ToString()
    }
}
```

Comment: the find control is returning NULL

Comment: @Rj. Is it the case that the checkbox isn't is the first column? You can always try `row.FindControl("chkCheckBox")` to search in the wholre row. Also, make sure your checkbox's ID is actually "chkCheckBox"

Comment: Yeah man, it's still returning as NULL. The control is added to the gridview at run-time. im not sure if this is the issue. (my second block of code in my OP)

Comment: @Rj. Yes, that is the issue, because you are not assiging an ID to the control (the name of the vairiable is not the ID of the control). Try adding the checkbox in design time, but make it invisible. Set it visible in your `gvShows_DataBound`